# Python no longer detected as a language in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python3

I'm genuinely confused and have no idea how this happened.

If I try to set the language to Python in a file, the option doesn't appear
[image: When searching Python in the "Select a Language" prompt, nothing appears]

Python files have the plain text icon and there is no syntax highlighting in files
[image: Python files have a plain text icon and no syntax highlighting]

I didn't modify anything related to VS Code. All I remember doing was uninstalling and reinstalling my Python 3.8.10 installation as it was originally 32 bit so I updated it to 64 bit.

Any one know how to solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the path Visual Studio Code is looking for within its settings

Answer (score 0):

Go to your extension manager (ctrl+shift+x) search for Python and make sure the official Python extension is installed.

Also be sure that you have python added to Windows PATH

*How to add Python to Windows PATH:*
https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path